# Стоит ли закэшировать меню в Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, кэширование

На сайте есть древовидное меню, которое содержит в себе три ступени: Категория А...n -> Подкатегория 1...n -> Пост 1...n
При этом, поскольку в одной категории может находиться с десятка два подкатегорий, в каждой из которых более десяти постов, то построение всей этой длинной как змея менюшки занимает довольно много ресурсов, если делать это налету, при загрузке страницы. При этом меню выводится как на страницах категорий, так и на страницах постов.

Каким образом лучше избавиться от построения меню на лету?

Меню может меняться только если добавляются / удаляются подкатегории или посты. При этом самих вариантов меню существует столько же сколько и Категорий А (у которых нет родительских категорий).

Имеет смысл генерировать / изменять меню в один какие-то моменты времени, а затем хранить его в базе или каким-то образом кэшировать?

Comment: Если меню меняется редко, то используйте кеш для его хранения.

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае поможет подзагрузка данных для меню через AJAX (пункты меню и ссылки берутся из БД). Другой вопрос, насколько у вас объемный код, лучше 100 строчек загрузить непосредственно при стартовой сборке DOM-дерева, чем прикручивать подзагрузку.

Comment: Код достаточно объемный. Но зачем грузиьть через AJAX, если можно скомпилировать меню заранее и брать из кэша, например?

Comment: @SurenderMeg там вопрос в объеме этого меню (сейчас и в дальнейшем). если порядка 200-300 пунктов, то проще сразу сделать в HTML, если там тысячи пунктов, которые периодически еще и меняются - лучше AJAX